# How to configure Blazor with Windows Authentication and IIS

Tags: iis, blazor

I'm having issues with my Blazor app and Windows Authentication after getting IIS hooked up to it. I've been through the steps in [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) however, everytime I go to the site, I get a chrome dialog asking me for a username and a password. My understanding is that IIS should be handling my windows creds and forwarding it to the site.

**Expected result**:

[image]

**Actual result**:

[image]

I see that IISExpress will run the website as my local domain user, which works just fine and the app lets me in. When I run the site from IIS (when it uses the apppool user) is what I run into issues. I need to be able to authenticate as my user without changing the user that the Apppool runs as.

Some information of the project

**launchSettings.json**:

```
{    
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": false,
    "iis": {
      "applicationUrl": "https://customersupport.dev.local",
      "sslPort": 0
    },
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:13394",
      "sslPort": 44318
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "Shelby.CustomerSupport": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "dotnetRunMessages": "true",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000"
    },
    "IIS": {
      "commandName": "IIS"
    }
  }
}
```

**web.config**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <security>
        <authentication>
          <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
          <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
        </authentication>
      </security>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="bin\Debug\net5.0\Shelby.CustomerSupport.exe" arguments="" stdoutLogEnabled="false" hostingModel="InProcess">
        <environmentVariables>
          <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT" value="443" />
          <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
        </environmentVariables>
      </aspNetCore>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: "everytime I go to the site, I get a chrome dialog asking me for a username and a password" and that's what we call Windows authentication. To suppress the prompt, follow guides like https://knowledge.kofax.com/Smart_Process_Applications_-_TotalAgility/Configuration/Configure_Chrome_To_Allow_Windows_Authentication_Without_Prompting